# Check for performance for single vs two user tables for different type of users in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, normalization, execution

I have a situation where I need to design the database for two types of users, let say TYPE1 and TYPE2. TYPE1 user is general users which are going to be millions and TYPE2 users are some kind of professionals which are going to be limited in the amount of record. 
I have made a common table for both of them called `users` table. Now the scenario is if I want to search a set of professionals by the city, which is the best-suited approach with respect to performance?

CASE 1: Having a single table for the user(Which actually helps in scalability)
CASE 2: Two separate table for both types of users

Comment: Having information in one, two or 20 tables doesn't impact much what MySQL does behind the scenes (it multiplexes writes to the HDD very efficiently). If you think that splitting something in more tables on a *single server* helps performance - you are wrong. This is why you always design databases in such a way that you can easily query it, add info or extrapolate info. This means 1 table is the way to go.

Comment: @Mjh It's not how it holds rather how it query to the DB. I mean suppose I have 5 Million records in DB having 1 Lakh of TYPE2 users and I am querying something for TYPE2 users, don't you think MySQL go through all the 5 million records for checking whether this row is for TYPE2? Will it not affect the performance?

Comment: Even if you had 100 million records, that's not a lot of data. If you query the db to ask how many users of certain type there is, then it will go through the entire table. If you query the table using type and username, then you can index the username. Users who are logged on, you can obtain info about them by using primary key. Don't make your life miserable by premature optimization.

Comment: If most of the columns are similar between the two types, use one table.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it will be having a single table for the `user`.

Put one more column `TYPE(TINYINT(1))` which can have value either `1(type 1)` or `2(type 2)`,which acts like a flag to distinguish between users.

### **Data type for Flag**

> According to the MySQL manual you can use bool and boolean which are
>   at the moment aliases of tinyint(1)

So you can query accoring to the value of `TYPE` for getting particular types of Users.

So the column `TYPE` can be

```
`TYPE` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

Which gives you a better performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also want to have single table but searching is going to be done on TYPE2 users which are very less compare to TYPE1 users. Do you think it will affect to the performance?

Comment: No i dont think so, but make that field as `TINY INT`.. which improve perfomance..

Comment: `ENUM` is also an excellent datatype, and it avoids the user converting between "type1" and "1".